# Congruence for the polynomials $(t+1)^n$

Tags: nt.number-theory, reference-request, co.combinatorics, polynomials

An interesting polynomial congruence is given by
$$A_n(t^m)\equiv \left(\frac{1+t+\cdots+t^{m-1}}m\right)^{n+1}A_n(t) \qquad \mod (t-1)^{n+1}, \tag1$$
where $A_n(t)$ are the *Eulerian polynomials* with generating function
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{A_n(t)}{(1-t)^{n+1}}\,\frac{x^n}{n!}=\frac1{1-t\,e^x}.$$
This result have been proved and reproved (for example, see the [more recent preprint](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2101.07384.pdf) by Ira Gessel).

> **QUESTION.** Let $f_n(t)=(t+1)^n$. Is there a similar (and non-trivial) congruence between $f_n(t^m)$ and $f_n(t)$, as in (1)?

**Remark.** My motivation is that both set of polynomials are symmetric and bimodal, so the question might be feasible.

Comment: You want a congruence between $f_n ( t^m)$ and a multiple of $f_n(t)$?

Comment: @WillSawin: thanks, I fixed accordingly.

Comment: If $m$ is odd, then there is a trivial identity. $f_n(t^m)= (t^{m-1} - t^{m-1} + \dots + t^2 - t + 1)^n f_n(t)$. I don't see how you could have a meaningful non-trivial congruence while that identity exists. But maybe if $m$ is even you could do something cool.